# Whats is the difference between using Convert and Cast in a Select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have put a question here

[Select the field as Distinct having data type as Text. Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494116/select-the-field-as-distinct-having-data-type-as-text-sql-server)

and I got two replies one is saying to use

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Subjects) FROM T1
```

and the other is saying to use

```
select distinct cast(Subjects as varchar) from T1
```

I tried both and they are working fine. I am wondering whats the difference between both.

Thanks.

Comment: The second one casts to `varchar(30)` rather than `max` but that is just because no length is specified. Not due to `CAST` vs `CONVERT`

Comment: They are only "working fine" because you didn't compare them on any strings greater than 30 characters. Did you see [my comment on the answer you accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494116/select-the-field-as-distinct-having-data-type-as-text-sql-server#comment30632399_20494273)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, performance is not a issue.(As far as your question describes both can be used and there is no difference between them but as `martin` said statement using `CAST` will cast to varchar(30) as it is it's default length)

```
CAST is an ANSI SQL-92

CONVERT is specific to SQL Server
```

`CONVERT` is specific to SQL Server, and allows for a greater breadth of flexibility when converting between date and time values, fractional numbers, and monetary signifiers.

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), GETDATE(),108)
--and the other is saying to use

select distinct cast(GETDATE() as VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Comment: Can you give an example where `CAST` preserves decimal places that `CONVERT` does not?

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, no difference.
Just that CAST is ANSI-SQL(complying to the standards) so the query will be portable between server technologies.

Convert is specific to sql server but provides a richer set of options to convert.

Suggest using cast for portability unless you have to do otherwise.

King Regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 0):

CONVERT more flexible when converting between date and time values, fractional numbers, and monetary signifiers.
CAST is the more ANSI-standard.

thats means that while the cast format is set to standard u can use a lot of formats in convert
for example

```
convert ( datetime , get date () , **format**)
```

in the format u can enter the number of the format.

101 mm/dd/yyyy

102 yyyy.mm.dd ANSI date with century

103 dd/mm/yyyy

104 dd.mm.yyyy

u can google for more formats.

there is no diff preformance wise or any other aspect